# sending data from android device to a tap top

Tags: java, android, sockets, bluetooth, serial-port

I have an android app that is running on an android device (phone / tablet).
I would like to create a connection between the device to a near by laptop in order to send some data from the android app to a java app that is running on the laptop.

From your experience, what would be the best / easiest way to accomplish that connection? 
Should i make a socket connection? Serial port connection? Bluetooth connection? Maybe wifi?
I think that a socket connection is the least favorite of mine for this particular project.

I should say that i have not tried any of those connection type on android in the past.

Any recommendation? I am open for suggestions.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use sockets via Wifi ! I managed to make it work and it's pretty easy :)

1. Make your laptop as Access Point
2. Connect your android to the local Access Point Network via Android Interface
3. Launch the C++ (or whatever) socket server on the laptop (Will set the port number)
4. Launch your Android app that open a socket on the same port number and read data through inputStreamBuffer

Here is an example of an AsyncTask that open a socket and read data

```
class WifiDataAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
    private Socket sock;
    private Context context;
    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private BufferedReader br;

    WifiDataAsyncTask(Context context, WifiManager wifiManager) {
        this.context = context;
        this.wifiManager = wifiManager;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Integer... numPort) {
        int rawChar;
        sock = new Socket();
        try {

            Log.d(TAG, "Creating socket on IP " + getIpAddress(wifiManager) + ":" + numPort[0]);
            sock.setReuseAddress(true);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error set reuseaddress");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress(getIpAddress(wifiManager), numPort[0]));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error connection socket");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (sock.isConnected()) {
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));

                StringBuilder toSave = new StringBuilder();
                // -1 : end of the stream
                // isCancelled() tells you if the asynctask has been cancelled in the Main Activity
                while ((rawChar = br.read()) != -1 && !isCancelled()) {
                    char c = (char) rawChar;
                    if (c == '\0') {
                        // Add the char to the string to save
                        toSave.append('\n');
                        // DO STUFF WITH YOUR STRING DATA
                        toSave.setLength(0);
                    } else {
                        toSave.append(c);
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error read InputStream:");
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
            try {
                closeConnection();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error close connection:");
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    private void closeConnection() throws IOException {
        // If InputStream Closed (Wifi disconnected or server stopped)
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } finally {
            sock.close();
            Log.d(TAG, "Socket closed");
            // Tell Main Activity that the socket has closed
            Intent intent = new Intent(context.getResources().getString(R.string.CloseSocketAction));
            context.sendBroadcast(intent);
        }
    }

    private String getIpAddress(WifiManager wifiManager) {
        DhcpInfo dhcpInfo = wifiManager.getDhcpInfo();
        byte[] ipAddress = convert2Bytes(dhcpInfo.serverAddress);
        try {
            return InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddress).getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private byte[] convert2Bytes(int hostAddress) {
        return new byte[]{(byte) (0xff & hostAddress),
                (byte) (0xff & (hostAddress >> 8)),
                (byte) (0xff & (hostAddress >> 16)),
                (byte) (0xff & (hostAddress >> 24))};
    }
}
```

The Main activity can be like this :

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {

    private final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
    private View mLayout;
    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    private WifiDataAsyncTask wifiDataAsyncTask;
    private CloseSocketReceiver closeSocketReceiver;

    class CloseSocketReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();

            if (action.equals(getResources().getString(R.string.CloseSocketAction))) {
                Log.d(TAG, "CloseSocketReceiver");
            }
        }
    }

    private void startWifiDataAsyncTask() {
        // Create AsyncTasks
        wifiDataAsyncTask = new WifiDataAsyncTask(getContext(), wifiManager);
        wifiDataAsyncTask.execute(getResources().getInteger(R.integer.NUMPORT));
    }

    private void stopWifiDataAsyncTask() {
        wifiDataAsyncTask.cancel(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_osselet, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        mLayout = view;

        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

        // Create receiver
        closeSocketReceiver = new CloseSocketReceiver();

    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getActivity().registerReceiver(closeSocketReceiver, new IntentFilter(getResources().getString(R.string.CloseSocketAction)));
    }

    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getActivity().unregisterReceiver(closeSocketReceiver);
    }
}
```

In the manifest, add the internet permission to use Wifi :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

And here is the C++ Server.cpp that send a String message :

```
#include <errno.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "Server.h"
#include "common.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

using namespace std;

Server::Server(int num_port) {
    this->num_port = num_port;

}

void Server::init() {   // Init socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if(sockfd < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening socket\n");
    }

    // Allow to reuse socket immediately after closing server
    int enabled = 1;
    if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &enabled, sizeof(int)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "setsockopt(SO_REUSEADDR) failed\n");
    }
    printf("Server Socket created on port %d\n", num_port);

    // Init server_addr
    bzero((char*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(num_port);

    // Init newsockfd
    newsockfd = -1;


}

Server::~Server() {
    close(sockfd);
    close(newsockfd);
}

void Server::bind() {
    // Binding socket
    if(::bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) < 0){
        fprintf(stderr, "Error Binding Socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void Server::listen(int maxClient) {
    printf("Look up for clients on port %d\n", num_port);

    // Define number of max clients
    ::listen(sockfd, maxClient);
}

int Server::start() {

    struct sockaddr_in cli_addr;
    socklen_t clilen = sizeof(cli_addr);

    fd_set set;
    struct timeval timeout;
    int rv;
    timeout.tv_sec = 1;
    timeout.tv_usec = 0;

    newsockfd = -1;

    // Check if newsockfd assigned or Ctrl-C handled
    while (newsockfd == -1 && signaled == 0) {
        // Reset into the loop
        // After listen returns, set have been updated and
        // starting another select will not wait on
        // the updated file descriptors
        // After first call, no client here, set updated and not 
        // listen anymore -> need to reset
        FD_ZERO(&set); /* Clear set */
        FD_SET(sockfd, &set); /* Add file descriptor to the set */

        rv = select(sockfd + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (rv == -1) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error select\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else if (rv == 0) {
            //fprintf(stderr, "Timeout occurred\n");
        }
        else {
            // Accept client
            newsockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr, &clilen);

            if(newsockfd < 0){
                fprintf(stderr, "Error Client not accepted by server\n"); 
            }
            // Set timeout to write
            struct timeval timeout;
            timeout.tv_sec = 0;
            timeout.tv_usec = 10;

            if (setsockopt (newsockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, (char *) &timeout, sizeof(timeout)) < 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "setsockopt(SO_SNDTIMEO) failed\n");
            }   
            printf("Client accepted on port %d\n", num_port);
        }
    }
    printf("Server.start() terminated\n");
    return newsockfd;       
}

int Server::sendData(char* toSend, int size) {
    // Check is socket closed
    int n = write(newsockfd, toSend, size);
    if (n < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error sending message\n"); 
    }
    else {
        //printf("Message %s sent to the client on port %d\n", toSend, num_port);
    }
    return n;
}   

void Server::closeClientSocket() {
    close(newsockfd);
}

void Server::stop() {
    printf("Closing sockets\n");
    close(newsockfd);
    close(sockfd);
}
```

And finally the Server.h

```
#ifndef SERVER_H
#define SERVER_H

#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
class Server {

    private:
        int num_port;
        int sockfd, newsockfd;
        struct sockaddr_in server_addr;

    public:
        Server(int num_port); // Constructor
        ~Server(); // Desctructor

        void init();
        void allowReuse();
        void bind();
        void listen(int);
        int start();
        int sendData(char*, int);
        void closeClientSocket();
        void stop();
};

#endif
```

Hope it helps !

Comment: Thank you, that would be a good start for me. As i said before sockets are the least favorable option for this project since i might not have internet access for the laptop at all times in order to make it a hot spot.  Also if i want to send data from the android app instead of receiving i just use `OutputStream` instead of the `InputStream`?

Comment: Yes you are right, use an OutputStream like this : `out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());` and then write data `out.write("test");`
And you don't need Internet Access to use socket. The Android Device is locally connected to your laptop Access Point.

Comment: So i just make an access point on the laptop, connect the android device to it using wifi and I'll be good to go?  When i was doing socket connection using java i had to open a specific port in order to listen to it and connect to it from the outside. Is it the same with hotspot? Where is the port determination on the android side?

Comment: By the way, should i make some special thing in the manifest of the app, some special permissions?

Comment: Yes that why it's easy to use :) Follow the steps I wrote. Actually, it is the server that will open the port not the wifi hotspot. Hotspot just allow you to establish a Wifi bridge between the devices. In the Server.cpp, I set the port to 1500 (don't use port number under 1000, used by the system). On the Android Asynctask, the `getResources().getInteger(R.integer.NUMPORT)` in the startDataWifiASynctask is also 1500.

Comment: Yes sorry, forgot to mention that, you have to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to use the Wifi !

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. So to sum things up: open port on laptop -> make a hotspot -> listen to this port on laptop java app -> connect android device to hotspot -> run android app. correct?

Comment: No :) I updated my steps list in the post above to make it more clear. Check it out !

Answer (score 0):

This example is shown using RX

**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mStartRX = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes();
    mStartTX = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes();

    if (mStartRX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED || mStartTX == TrafficStats.UNSUPPORTED) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alert.setTitle("Uh Oh!");
        alert.setMessage("Your device does not support traffic stat monitoring.");
        alert.show();
    } else {
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
    }
}
```

We need to update our display and reschedule the runnable:

```
private final Runnable mRunnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        TextView RX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.RX);
        TextView TX = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TX);
        long rxBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalRxBytes() - mStartRX;
        RX.setText(Long.toString(rxBytes));
        long txBytes = TrafficStats.getTotalTxBytes() - mStartTX;
        TX.setText(Long.toString(txBytes));
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 1000);
    }
};
```

Comment: What is `RX`? Is that a library? Where is the sending process is being performed? what type of connection are we talking about here, serial?

Comment: Read about RX here:

https://medium.com/@kevalpatel2106/code-your-next-android-app-using-rxjava-d1db30ac9fcc

Communication is via wifi

Comment: I hope I helped you